# getUserObjectWithId not available on Swift?

Tags: parse-platform

```
let user:PFUser = PFQuery.getUserObjectWithId((JobApplicantsID[i] as? String)!)!
```

Im trying to get a PFUser object from a String ID from an array but the error came out as `getUserObjectWithId is not available in swift`

Comment: that's what it says. not sure what you're asking really...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Parse does not have this function included with their swift package, not sure why. Also, I have only had success getting a user that is not the current user by making the request from my cloud code. I think Parse denies any request from iOS code for security reasons. If you have cloud code set up in your app, I would recommend querying in that. This is what the request looks like inside of my cloud code function:

```
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("objectId", objectIdPassedIn);
    query.first({
        success: function(result) {
            if (result != undefined) {
                console.log("Result: " + result);
                response.success(result);
            } else {
                response.error("user with given Id does not exist");
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log(error);
            response.error(error);  
        }
    });
```

This gets the first user who has a matching objectId, and because users can never have the same objectId, it should be the only user.